# HtmlPage.window.navigate in Internet Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, silverlight-5.0

I have developed a small Silverlight app, and everything works as expected when testing it with Chrome. Part of my application involves downloading a ISO image from the server where the app is hostede. To facilitate this i use the following code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://mytetSite/somefile.iso");
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uri);
```

When testing the app with Chrome, a file is downloaded using the native Chrome downloader thingy.
When using Internet Explorer 9 nothing happens when the above code is executed, i also tried using the Hyperlinkbutton controll (and settings navigateuri) - but same result: Works in chrome, but *nothing* happens when pressing the button in internet explorer.

What could cause the above - and how would i go about fixing it? (I don't even get a popup warning dialog in internet explorer).